# Время в php или нет? Хелп

Tags: php

Только недавно появилось php в моей жизни. Но очень хочется спросить помощи по конкретному примеру. Все знаю простою логику онлайн игры. При нажатии на ссылку, если все ок то, записать значение в базу, в нашем случае [построить дом]. Условие. Дом должен строиться определенное количество времени в зависимости от чего либо. Это крон? Или как сделать по средствам php. Куда копать, чтобы нормально копалось?

Comment: Мне советуют для создания простого алгоритма использовать функцию записи в бд. Если построен дом записать данные в бд.Время. Простая работа с временем. Дом построиться только тогда, когда будет выполнено условие **

Answer (score 1):

Да это крон, ну или его вариация.

К примеру когда-то нужно было реализовать похожие условия: строим дом, и как только отстроится - отрисовать в браузере клиента. Для того что бы это реализовать я не делал крон на стороне сервера, а вынес это на клиент. Браузер с некой периодичностью дергал (асинхронно) php скрипт проверки готовности дома (утрирую) и если все готово то перерисовывал у себя.

Может возникнуть вопрос (чисто из логики игры): ну вот строим мы дом который производит ресурсы, но в это время клиент не подключен - что же делать? Тут был реализован другой механизм - скрипт проверки при первом подключении клиента видит что дом построен и давно. Соответственно берет и находит точки во времени когда была закончена стройка и текущее время, ну и по этому диапазону накидывает игроку ресурсов, а выглядит так будто дом все это время их производил.